# BotからTeamsへ送信したメッセージ上のハイパーリンクのプレビューが表示されない。

Tags: python, framework

BotからTeamsのチャットへ送信するメッセージの文字列へ以下のタグ情報を追加しています。
`<a href='対象となるURL'>'アンカーテキスト'</a>`

チャット上でハイパーリンクとしては機能しているのですが、
リンク先のプレビューがメッセージ上で表示されません。
Botから送信したメッセージにプレビューを表示するためには何か記法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「Botから」ということは、人間が投稿した時は意図した通りにプレビューが表示されるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。人間がメッセージの入力欄にURLを貼り付けた際にはプレビューが表示されました。